# One page site scrollTo does not work when jQuery scrollbar plugin is added

Tags: jquery, scrollto, slimscroll

I created a single page website and I am using a navigation to scroll to the different sections of the website. Now I would like to change the scrollbar to something similar to slimScroll. The problem is that when I add this plugin the scrollTo on the website does not seem to work. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

slimScroll doesn't really scroll the site, it just [changes the `top` property of your container](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/blob/master/jquery.slimscroll.js#L357).